# How to use the System.Data.SqlClient namespace in the Azure Function V4 on the portal

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core

I have one requirement to use the system.data.sqlclient library in the Azure Function V4 on the portal.
When I tried it this way but it return the error.
Could you please help me how to use the library in the Azure Function on the portal.

My run.csx file

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

I am getting this error while executing the function on the portal.

> run.csx(7,20): error CS1069: The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly

I have develop function App on the VS Code and use the library it's working fine as well as when I downgrade my function App from V4 to V3. It's working fine with same code but when I am trying to upgrade the function App with V4, it returns the error.

see here : https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1512

Comment: Would be great if you share the error you get.

Comment: run.csx(7,20): error CS1069: The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1512

Comment: Can you try https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead (it is compatible, but other namespace and supports latest .net

Comment: I tried it, but it was not working

Comment: Not working in what sense?

Comment: Please try to give as much  context as possible, it makes it easier to help

Comment: github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1512

Comment: That is about system.data.sqlclient, not microsodt.data.sqlclient so what happens when you use that one? Trying to help here but if you keep linking to GitHub issues it is difficult

Comment: I have tried the both dll on Azure function still, I am getting same error.

Comment: It appears to be a limitation with the Azure Function portal experience. The .csx format isnt compatible with the SQL client packages. Both Microsoft.Data.SQLclient and system.Data.SqlClient are in compatible. Please develop function in Visual studio in your local machine where you can add the system.Data.SqlClient nuget package and then publish to Azure function

Comment: I am required to create functions on a portal. When I downgraded the function from V4 developed by csx format to V3, it worked fine. The issue only arose when I moved the function app to V4.